# Событие "mousemove" не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, события

Надо, чтобы падающие черточки разлетались при наведении мыши

```js
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  pos_x = e.clientX + 10,
    pos_y = e.clientY + 10
});
```

Не срабатывает. Что тут не так?

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/u6dmoLrt/3/

Comment: Откройте консоль, у Вас переменная `canvas` выбрасывает `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже ответили listener должен быть в методе `init` так-как там где он сейчас находится `canvas` ещё не определен. Но кроме того, просто поменять x/y в listener-е не получится так-как у каждой черточки своя x/y и прийдетса менять её у каждой черточки. И это нужно делать не в listener-е а в `animate` а то как только мышь перестанет двигаться, перестанут разлетаться и черточки.

Я вот тут написал версию вашего кода с изменениями которые я перечислил и с небольшой добавкой и очисткой кода:

https://jsfiddle.net/u1qoc806/

Answer (score 1):

Поместите код `canvas.addEventListener...` внутрь функции `init` после `canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas");`.